# 'undefined reference to' errors trying to compile with Make

Tags: c, compiler

I had a working Makefile that successfully compiled and built a basic program to toggle and LED on my stm32-h103 board. I have since attempted to add and use FreeRTOS in my program. I have added in the FreeRTOS paths into my Makefile however I am getting the following errors when I run make.

```
src/app.a(startup.o):(.isr_vectors+0x2c): undefined reference to `vPortSVCHandler'
src/app.a(startup.o):(.isr_vectors+0x38): undefined reference to `xPortPendSVHandler'
src/app.a(startup.o):(.isr_vectors+0x3c): undefined reference to `xPortSysTickHandler'
src/app.a(main.o): In function `main':
/home/matthew/Work/22_ARM-Firmware/HomeAutomationControllerPrototype/src/main.c:36: undefined reference to `xTaskGenericCreate'
/home/matthew/Work/22_ARM-Firmware/HomeAutomationControllerPrototype/src/main.c:37: undefined reference to `vTaskStartScheduler'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am very new to Makefiles so am unsure what else I must add to get the code to compile.

My two make files are:

Makefile.common

```
TOP=$(shell readlink -f "$(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))")
PROGRAM=main
LIBDIR=$(TOP)/libs
FREERTOSDIR=$(TOP)/src/FreeRTOS/Source

#Adust the following line to the library in use
STMLIB=$(LIBDIR)/STM32F10x_StdPeriph_Lib_V3.6.1/Libraries

#Adjust TypeOfMCU in use, see CMSIS file "stm32f10x.h"
#STM32F103RBT (128KB FLASH, 20KB RAM) --> STM32F10X_MD
TypeOfMCU=STM32F10X_MD
#STM32F103RET (512KB FLASH, 64KB RAM) --> STM32F10X_HD
#TypeOfMCU=STM32F10X_HD

TC=arm-none-eabi
CC=$(TC)-gcc
LD=$(TC)-ld -v
OBJCOPY=$(TC)-objcopy
AR=$(TC)-ar
GDB=$(TC)-gdb

INCLUDE=-I$(TOP)/inc
INCLUDE+=-I$(STMLIB)/CMSIS/Include
INCLUDE+=-I$(STMLIB)/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F10x/Include
INCLUDE+=-I$(STMLIB)/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F10x/Source/Templates
INCLUDE+=-I$(STMLIB)/STM32F10x_StdPeriph_Driver/inc
INCLUDE+=-I$(STMLIB)/STM32_USB-FS-Device_Driver/inc
INCLUDE+=-I$(FREERTOSDIR)/include
INCLUDE+=-I$(FREERTOSDIR)/portable/GCC/ARM_CM3
INCLUDE+=-I$(TOP)/src


COMMONFLAGS=-g -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb
COMMONFLAGSlib=$(COMMONFLAGS)

#Commands for general Makefile and src Makefile
ifeq ($(OptSRC),0)
    COMMONFLAGS+=-O0
    InfoTextSrc=src (no optimize, -O0)
else ifeq ($(OptSRC),1)
    COMMONFLAGS+=-O1
    InfoTextSrc=src (optimize time+ size+, -O1)
else ifeq ($(OptSRC),2)
    COMMONFLAGS+=-O2
    InfoTextSrc=src (optimize time++ size+, -O2)
else ifeq ($(OptSRC),s)
    COMMONFLAGS+=-Os
    InfoTextSrc=src (optimize size++, -Os) 
else ifeq ($(OptSRC),3)
    COMMONFLAGS+=-O3
    InfoTextSrc=src (full optimize, -O3)
else
    COMMONFLAGS+=-O3
    CFLAGS += -D RELEASE_PUBLIC
    InfoTextSrc=src (full optimize and readout protected, -O4)
endif
CFLAGS+=$(COMMONFLAGS) -Wall -Werror $(INCLUDE)
CFLAGS+=-D $(TypeOfMCU)
CFLAGS+=-D VECT_TAB_FLASH

#Commands for libs Makefile
ifeq ($(OptLIB),0)
    COMMONFLAGSlib+=-O0
    InfoTextLib=libs (no optimize, -O0)
else ifeq ($(OptLIB),1)
    COMMONFLAGSlib+=-O1
    InfoTextLib=libs (optimize time+ size+, -O1)
else ifeq ($(OptLIB),2)
    COMMONFLAGSlib+=-O2
    InfoTextLib=libs (optimize time++ size+, -O2)
else ifeq ($(OptLIB),s)
    COMMONFLAGSlib+=-Os
    InfoTextLib=libs (optimize size++, -Os)
else
    COMMONFLAGSlib+=-O3
InfoTextLib=libs (full optimize, -O3)
endif
CFLAGSlib+=$(COMMONFLAGSlib) -Wall -Werror $(INCLUDE)
CFLAGSlib+=-D $(TypeOfMCU)
CFLAGSlib+=-D VECT_TAB_FLASH
```

And my src Makefile

```
# src Makefile

include ../Makefile.common

OBJS+=startup.o
OBJS+=main.o

all: src

src: app.a

app.a: $(OBJS)
    $(AR) cr app.a $(OBJS)

.PHONY: src clean tshow

clean:
    rm -f app.a $(OBJS)
```

Comment: Where are you telling it to compile the free rtos .c files?  I believe you need OBJS+= lines for these.

Answer (score 3):

As well as pointing to the header files so your source knows what functions are available, you also have to link in the code for those functions.

You are referencing the `.h` files fine, but FreeRTOS also consists of many `.c` files.  Those `.c` files need to be compiled along with your code and then linked together during the final phase of compilation.

Personally I would compile all of the FreeRTOS files separately as an individual step, then combine them into an archive file, say `libFreeRTOS.a` which you can then link against using `-lFreeRTOS` (similar to how you're making `app.a`, but using the proper `libXXX.a` format so it works with `-l`).

Comment: To be honest i'm all rather confused over this example makefile im using. I am used to seeing rules as to how the startup.o and main.o files would be generated. i.e. from time with ATMega,                                                                                                     

bounce1.o: bounce1.c ../../drivers/avr/pio.h ../../drivers/avr/system.h ../../utils/pacer.h
 $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

Is there any examples I can follow to configure my Makefile to build FreeRTOS.